# Oracle 10g forms not opening in form developer on Windows7 Professional

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

Following are the error details produced just before oracle form developer closes itself when tried to open an Oracle form (.fmb) file.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: frmbld.exe
  Application Version:  10.1.2.0
  Application Timestamp:    42d63632
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18229
  Fault Module Timestamp:   51fb10c6
  Exception Code:   ebad198c
  Exception Offset: 0000812f
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: eb4a
  Additional Information 2: eb4a9e76ce8297047181d2597f2e35d7
  Additional Information 3: cec2
  Additional Information 4: cec2494d9afd93122704972a7bd38028

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

It is typically observed with files having size more than 700-800 kb.

Please guide how to resolve this problem.
Following are related searches which didn't provide clear solution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-can-i-install-oracle-10g-and-forms-reports-10g/c1a00001-2cd8-44e5-9930-d42a5136cab2

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2326324

Following window displays exact version of Oracle 10g forms developer -
[image: Oracle 10g version details]

Comment: Many of the forms below mentioned size open seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Standard forms 10 installation is made for windows XP.
There are some problems opening this installation on windows7.
On oracle support are patches available to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you nightfox79, have checked with Oracle support but no patches found as such. It would be helpful if you could point to links.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite "solution" is to install VirtualBox, put Windows XP onto it, install Developer Suite and use it without problems. When I change the computer, I simply copy the virtual machine onto a new PC, save myself from yet another (and another, and another ...) painful installation process and use Forms (& Reports) *instantly*. I'd suggest you to do the same, if you want.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot, will consider this option. At organisational level, it will be hard to have virtual box at company machines, but still I will have talk with administrators...

Comment: You're welcome. Basically, your best option is to check certification matrices, see which Oracle software is certified & supported on which operating systems, sit and talk about the options you have and make a plan for the next several years. For example, if you plan to upgrade to Windows 10, you wouldn't be installing Forms 10g but 12c and have a stable, supported environment.